# Why isn't my JLabel centering in the middle of JPanel (GridBagLayout) in Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, layout-manager

I am attempting to add the following `JLabel` to the center of a `JPanel`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JLabel {

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        int[] xpoints = {230, 270, 290, 290, 270, 230, 210, 210};
        int[] ypoints = {37, 37, 87, 115, 165, 165, 115, 87};

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 8 );    
    }
}
```

To the following `JPanel`:

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel();
jp.add(dp);
```

But the `DrawingPanel` `JPanel` won't even show up. What's up the problem? Thank you

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `GridBagLayout` uses `GridBagConstraints` to manage positioning. Create a `GridBagConstraints` object, and add it when you add you panel: `jp.add(dp, gbc)`

Comment: Your `DrawingPanel` has no defined size details, so it's been sized to `0x0` by the layout manager for starters...

Comment: Your "shape" won't be centered, because, well...it's not.  Your coordinates should be calculated based on known values (like the components width and height), not some magic numbers you made up...also, why are extending from `JLabel`....?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why isn't the size defined? It has coordinates. Shouldn't those be size?

Comment: Size is defined by the `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` methods, these are called WAY before any painting is done.  Also, based on your painting, what information could possible describe the physical size of the component to the outside world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Without any sizing hints, your component will be automatically sized to `0x0` as that's it's default size
2. Your output won't be centered, because, well...it's not.  You've used a bunch of "magic" numbers which have no relevance in the real world.  How do you know you component is going to be a given size?
3. All coordinates within a component's paint methods and contextual to the component, that is, the top/left corner is `0x0`...
4. Why are you extending from `JLabel`?  `JLabel` has enough complex functionality without you trying to add it...

You should based you calculations on known values, like the components width and height, you should also provide some idea of the preferred size you would like your component to be under optimal circumstances, for example...

[image: Shape]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new DrawingPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        public DrawingPanel() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            g2d.translate(insets.top, insets.left);

            int width = getWidth() - 1 - (insets.left + insets.right);
            int height = getHeight() - 1 - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

            int vHalf = height / 2;
            int hHalf = width / 2;
            int vPos = vHalf / 4;
            int hPos = hHalf / 4;

            int[] xpoints = {
                0,
                hHalf - hPos,
                hHalf + hPos,
                width,
                width,
                hHalf + hPos,
                hHalf - hPos,
                0
            };
            int[] ypoints = {
                vHalf - vPos,
                0,
                0, 
                vHalf - vPos,
                vHalf + vPos,
                height,
                height,
                vHalf + vPos,
            };

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```